# Is it secure to remove special character from activation key

Tags: security, user-interface

In my application I am creating a activation key of 64 characters. 
It is having special characters like

```
+ =
```

While framing url we are doing url encode. But if user do a copy of the url from his email client , in some client url is getting url decoded.

Some suggestion is to remove these special character with charters which don't require url encode. 
Will it going to create any issue in security as character set will be limited ?

Comment: Your keysize should be just fine if you are using 64 character and only doing a-z 0-9 .  That gives you 36 ^ 64  possible keys.  Quite a few :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use just alphanumeric characters, and make it case-insensitive, you will have 36 possible characters.  Since your key is 64 characters long, you end up with a keyspace that is quite big (Larger than a GUID).

Depending what you are trying to protect this against (I assume brute forcing legitimate keys), so long as your algorithm for generating them is sufficient, you should not be at any risk of generating keys that are easily guessed.